# Is there a command to clear the screen of MYSQL under Windows?

Tags: shell, mysql

Is there a command to clear the screen of MYSQL under Windows?

I could not find it. Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot clear screen in `mysql` client on Windows. On Linux there are two ways to do it `\! clear` or `system clear` and `Ctrl+L`. I've thought on Windows it would be possible to do this with `\! cls` or `system cls` but that is not the case. Windows `mysql` has not `\!` or `system` command. Quote from docs: 'The system command works only in Unix.'

Comment: CTRL + L hehehe

Answer (score 0):

Use the "clear" command. Details are at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-commands.html.

Comment: Does 'clear' command clear the screen? It could only clear my previous input command but not the whole screen of the cmd on my computer.

Comment: No, it does not.